# Loading NumPy array in dataset parser function

Tags: tensorflow

I am using a TensorFlow Dataset to consume data from my hard drive. The data is stored in NumPy arrays, and the paths for the NumPy arrays are stored in a text file. When creating the dataset, I am using the `dataset.map()` function to map each path to a NumPy array.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
def parser(path):
    x = np.load(path)
    return x

paths = ['data1.npy', 'data2.npy', 'data3.npy', 'data4.npy', ... ]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((paths))
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=parser)
```

However, this gives the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'read'`

The error refers to the line `x = np.load(path)`. So it seems that I cannot load a NumPy array in this way in my parser function, because `path` is not actually a string, but a Tensor.

What is the correct way to do this? I want to avoid using TFRecords if possible.

---

I have also tried wrapping the load function as follows:

```
x = tf.py_func(np.load(path))
```

But this gives me the same error on that line:

`AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feeding .npy (numpy files) into tensorflow data pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889482/feeding-npy-numpy-files-into-tensorflow-data-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `np.load` requires a string as input, but get Tensor.
You can use `tf.py_func` to wrap load function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried tried this, however, I still get the same error message (see above).

Comment: use `tf.py_func` like this:   `x = tf.py_func(np.load, path, tf.string)`.  You can see the link @jdehesa provide, there is a very good example.