# Loading a NumPy array into a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

According to the TensorFlow webpage at (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/programmers_guide/datasets), the `tf.read_file` can be used to load an image file from a given filename, and convert it to a Tensor:

```
image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)
```

In my case however, I want to load a NumPy array rather than an image. So the `filename` above points to a NumPy array on my machine.

If I were to use `tf.read_file(filename)` on this filename, then according to the documentation, this function returns a string Tensor (a byte array). How can I convert this into a Tensor representing the data in the NumPy array? Is there an equivalent function to `tf.image.decode_image()` for decoding a NumPy array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feeding .npy (numpy files) into tensorflow data pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889482/feeding-npy-numpy-files-into-tensorflow-data-pipeline)